# Mantain a local mysql db that is synced with a remote production db for testing

Tags: mysql, database, testing, synchronization

I'd like to do some analysis on data that exists on a production DB. For obvious reasons I maintain a local copy of the db(mysql), however I have some additional requirements:

1. I'd like to sync the local db with the production db easily. A
   manual sync that I can execute via CLI is fine
2. I'd like to be able to specify the tables that:

   - Should not be downloaded
   - Should contain data only for the last x days
   - Should contain the entire dataset

Any ideas/tools how to do this? My local setup is : MacOS, Sequel Pro, MySQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have access directly to your production system from your development box, a simple dump and restore is easy:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --host production -A \
  | mysql --host localhost
```

That `-A` option means all databases, all tables. If you want specific databases, you can specify them:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction  --host production \
  --databases eenie meenie miney moe \
  | mysql --host localhost
```

It would be a good idea to specify the databases, because that way you won't dump and restore your `mysql` database, where MySQL passwords and privileges are stored.

There's also a `--tables` option, but the usage of it is not clear from the docs, and I seldom use that option. Not sure what the syntax is.

If you don't have direct access to production, you'll have to do this in two stages, one step you run on the server to dump data to a file:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --databases eenie meenie miney moe \
  > dump.sql
```

Then download the file to your local workstation, and then load the dump file into your MySQL database:

```
mysql --host localhost < dump.sql
```

If you want more flexibility, there's a community tool called [mydumper](https://launchpad.net/mydumper), which allows you to put a list of databases & tables into a file. This tool is free, but you might have to compile it from source yourself.

Unfortunately, getting only the last X days is more tricky. Data doesn't have any implicit concept of *when* it was created.

Mysqldump has an option `--where` so you can add a condition to each query that dumps data. But it can only put conditions on data *values* by column name. For example if you had a timestamp column of the same name in every table, which reliably indicates the time the data was last modified (i.e. you have always maintained it with a trigger or something).

```
mysqldump --single-transaction  --host production \
  --databases eenie meenie miney moe \
  --where "updatedAt > NOW() - INTERVAL 6 DAY" \
  | mysql --host localhost
```

If you don't have that column in every table, this won't work.

Another alternative is to dump and restore the table definitions only, not the data.

```
mysqldump --single-transaction  --host production --no-data \
  --databases eenie meenie miney moe \
  | mysql --host localhost
```

Then as a separate step use the server's binary logs to grab all changes to data since six days ago using the [mysqlbinlog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlbinlog.html) tool. This you must run on the server.

```
mysqlbinlog --start-datetime="2017-02-02 00:00:00" mysql-binlog.* \
  > replay.sql

...download replay.sql...
```

Then load those changes into your local database:

```
mysql --host localhost < replay.sql
```

This is probably not really what you want, because what does "last six days of data" mean? What if you used an UPDATE to modify data within the past 4 days, but the data it modified was originally created 16 days ago. The binlog is a sequence of SQL changes, not data.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is extremely well detailed and thorough!